# Where is Unity3D Project Wizard project list stored on Linux/Mac?

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, cross-platform, wizard, regedit

In Windows, the project list is stored on the Regedit at this location:

[image: ...]

But where is this located on Linux or Mac? I want to do a program that need to use this paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for MacOS:

```
~/Library/Preferences⁩/com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x.plist
```